# Зависает приложение при открытии фрагмента с картой

Tags: android, android-fragment, google-maps, mapview

Есть несколько фрагментов. Если в каком то фрагменте запустить новый поток
`Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable())...` потом обязательно в `onPause()` выполняю `thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.
Далее если попытаться открыть фрагмент с картой то приложение просто зависает..

Мало времени на решении.

Google Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.google_map_view, container, false);
    googleMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    googleMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            gMap = googleMap;
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Открываю фрагмент так

```
GoogleMapViewFragment fragment = new GoogleMapViewFragment();
if (bundle!=null) fragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.replace(R.id.frgmCont, fragment, fragmentClass);
if (backStack) transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentClass);
transaction.commit();
```

А если в самом фрагменте карты запустить `Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable())...` то уже этот фрагмент не убирается т.е. недоступно переход на другой фрагмент (все зависает при replace)

Пробовал переделать на AsyncTask - все работает. Но это в одном месте, а чтобы переделать во всем проекте это месяц надо сидеть :(

Comment: А где Ваш поток то? `interrupt()` сам по себе ничего не делает, только ставит флаг в состояние interrupted, а обрабатывать это состояние Вы должны сами.

Comment: дело в том что если даже поток нечего не выполняет (пустое тело потока) происходит зависание..

Например: Открываем фрагмент карты и инициализируем новый поток, далее пытаемся открыть новый фрагмент - все зависает.. А если не инициализировать новый поток то все нормально

Comment: `currentThread()` - это обращение к текущему потоку. В `onPause()` это будет главный поток, а не порождённый Вами. Вызывайте `interrupt()` у Вашего потока: `thread.interrupt()`

Comment: Все равно так-же. если у thread вызвать currentThread() - будет получен UI поток? Я думал что будет получен как раз таки поток thread который был создан new Thread(). Можете направить где это разжевано?

Comment: Хотя, вроде помогло. Но все равно объясни пожалуйста) Thread.currentThread() - получает поток в котором выполняется т.е. если выполняется в отдельном потоке то получает отдельный поток. thread.currentThread() - получит тоже самое хотя и функция вызывается из thread?

Comment: Зачем потоку искать самого себя - ведь Ваша переменная `thread` и так на него указывает. А статический метод `Thread.currentThread()` находит и возвращает ссылку на поток, из которого вызван. Все системные события (ака `onPause`) вызываются в UI-потоке и поэтому `Thread.currentThread()`, вызванный в этих событиях вернёт  ссылку на него.